# How to add css based on another value?

Tags: jquery

i want to hide a `class` when a `value is not = 1`

```
   (function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
          if (!$('.class1').value='1') {
             $('.class2').css("display","none");;
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```

but it is not working...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ( $('.class1').val() !== "1" ) {
      $('.class2').hide();
    }
  });
 })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if ($('.class1').val() != '1') {
        $('.class2').css("display","none");;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
  $('.class1').val() != '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.class1')` will yield a reference to a jQuery object wrapping zero or more elements. It will not be a reference to a DOMNode. You do not at that point have access to any property named `value`. There is a function called `val` that will yield the value of the first element matched by the selector, if any.

```
if($('.class1').val() != '1') {
    $('.class2').hide();
}
```

Furthermore, you're trying to use `=` to check for equality, but `=` is only used for assignment. You should use `==` in conditions. Now that you're looking for the inverse of equality, you shouldn't use `!X==Y` but `X!=Y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class2').toggle( $('.class1').val().trim() != '1' );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcJn4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ( $('.class1').val() != "1" ) {
    $('.class2').attr('style','display:none;');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is single `=` equal here:

```
if (!$('.class1').value='1')
```

you can change to `==` or `===`:

```
if (!$('.class1').value === '1')
```

or this way:

```
if ($('.class1').value !== '1')
```